# Once it has taken input(words) from a file, how to terminate at a specific word?

Tags: java, echo, java.util.scanner, stdin

How would I go about making my program terminate once it reaches a specific word from a file. So far, I have it printing out all the words from the file which I want. "input" contains the words "one two three four galumph" just like that.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
class EchoWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc2 = null;
        try {
            sc2 = new Scanner(new File("input"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
            Scanner s2 = new Scanner(sc2.nextLine());
            while (sc2.hasNext()) {
                String s = s2.next();
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your condition? You need a condition...

Comment: I think you have a mistake. `while (sc2.hasNext())` should be `while (s2.hasNext())`. Not that I understand why you're using 2 scanners to begin with.

Comment: Cleaned my program up and figured it out thanks!